# wiremock path param matching

Tags: java, regex, integration-testing, wiremock

I need to create very basic mapping stup for `wiremock` server for the integration tests.
I am calling the POST with the payload on url that has path param in it:
`/ngdms/odrers/{order-id}`

this is the mapping stup I want to match to that call:

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPathPattern": "/ngdms/orders/*"
  },
  "response": {
   ...
   }
}
```

and the wiremock says:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Closest stub                                             | Request                                                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           |
POST                                                       | POST
[path regex] /ngdms/orders/*                               | /ngdms/orders/b41a627e-6981-403a-94cd-c225b8036ef1  <<<<< URL does not match
                                                           |
                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

so what is the regex `urlPathPattern` that will match basically everything (will be uuid eventually), please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Java's regex pattern, `*` is a quantifier, meaning it tells the pattern *how many* of the preceding token(s) to match.

A simple catchall would be `.*` (`.` is the symbol for any character).

```js
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPathPattern": "/ngdms/orders/.*"
  },
  "response": {
   ...
   }
}
```